# Using Office 2019 and can't see my outlook calendar appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2019

I just set up a new dell laptop with Office 2019 and set up outlook email. All good but calendar entries missing though I can see them fine on my old laptop - any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On non cloud based versions of office, your calendar is often only stored locally, you will see "(This computer only)" next to the calendar in Outlook if this is true. So when you set up your new laptop, all your mail was pulled from the server, but your calendar that was only stored locally on your old laptop could not be accessed.

You can make a .pst backup of your calendar on your old laptop by following the steps below, which can then be imported to your new laptop.

1. Open Outlook on old laptop
2. Click File
3. Click Open & Export
4. Click Import/Export
5. Click Export to a file
6. Click Outlook Data File (.pst)
7. Select the Calendar folder
8. Save the backup somewhere accessible.

You then want to put this backup on a usb stick or cloud storage accessible from the new laptop and import the calendar file.

The first four steps are as above

1. Open Outlook on new laptop
2. Click File
3. Click Open & Export
4. Click Import/Export
5. Click Import from another program or file
6. Click Outlook Data File (.pst)
7. Navigate to the usb where you saved the backup and select it.
8. Select Calendar as the folder to import from
9. Select "Import items to the same folder in: YOUREMAIL@EMAIL.com"

If the last step fails, you can start the steps from within your calendar on the new laptop and use the "Import items into the current folder" option in step 9.

Comment: This was a great fix for me - worked perfectly first time in 2 minutes. Note the file may be large - I had tried to cut USB bit by emailing it to myself but too large to send - really easy fix

Comment: Glad to hear you're back up and running! If you wouldn't mind, please take a minute to accept the answer as the accepted answer so that future visitors can see there's a solution!